# Why don't we put anchor peers inside channel config for first time generate?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

We all knew the [Hyperledger Fabric Sample](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples) when start working with HF, I have a question for the beginning when I started learning. To deploy the **test-network** then create a test channel, we need to follow some steps like below *(I took them from the createChannel.sh script)*

```
## Create channeltx
infoln "Generating channel create transaction '${CHANNEL_NAME}.tx'"
createChannelTx

## Create anchorpeertx
infoln "Generating anchor peer update transactions"
createAncorPeerTx

FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$PWD/../config/

## Create channel
infoln "Creating channel ${CHANNEL_NAME}"
createChannel

## Join all the peers to the channel
infoln "Join Org1 peers to the channel..."
joinChannel 1
infoln "Join Org2 peers to the channel..."
joinChannel 2

## Set the anchor peers for each org in the channel
infoln "Updating anchor peers for org1..."
updateAnchorPeers 1
infoln "Updating anchor peers for org2..."
updateAnchorPeers 2

successln "Channel successfully joined"
```

I feel so concerned, we need to do **createChannelTx** and **createAncorPeerTx** then **createChannel** and **updateAnchorPeers**, let's lookup the code of **[configtxgen](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/c31cfacb4c2642d6786322a6e35c72c21bf2f5c5/cmd/configtxgen/main.go#L82)** tool

```
updated := proto.Clone(original).(*cb.ConfigGroup) 

originalOrg, ok := original.Groups[channelconfig.ApplicationGroupKey].Groups[asOrg]
if !ok {
    return errors.Errorf("org with name '%s' does not exist in config", asOrg)
}

if _, ok = originalOrg.Values[channelconfig.AnchorPeersKey]; !ok {
    return errors.Errorf("org '%s' does not have any anchor peers defined", asOrg)
}

delete(originalOrg.Values, channelconfig.AnchorPeersKey)

updt, err := update.Compute(&cb.Config{ChannelGroup: original}, &cb.Config{ChannelGroup: updated})
```

What did they do? Just remove AnchorPeer from orginal config and compute before and after to create an update, back with my question. **Do we have any special problems to not generate anchor peer with channel and send them all to order once?**

Additional information: I'm using fabric 2.2 LTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[fabric-2.2/configtxgen](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/commands/configtxgen.html)
In the document

`-outputAnchorPeersUpdate` is DEPRECATED

fabric-2.x ~ will remove outputANchorPeersUpdate
ref : [FAB-17427](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-17427?jql=text%20%7E%20%22outputAnchorPeersUpdate%22)

In the future, the following code will be modified to reflect this in the configtxgen process.

```
if_, ok = originalOrg.Values[channelconfig.AnchorPeersKey]; !ok {
      return errors.Errorf("org'%s' does not have any anchor peers defined", asOrg)
}

delete(originalOrg.Values, channelconfig.AnchorPeersKey)
```

```
   -outputAnchorPeersUpdate string
         [DEPRECATED] Creates a config update to update an anchor peer (works only with the default channel creation, and only for the first update)
```

The option is DEPRECATED.
Probably from the 2.x version, it will be implemented to add to the genesis block through the configtx.yaml file without performing channel update.

Comment: Thank for your response but "however, it was not enough to configure the anchor peer." which point is missed in the config.

Comment: Second , you event can update anchor peer before peer join channel

Comment: Third, I guess they seem put everything to configtx.yaml to save time or something else  I don;t know

Comment: First, 'it was not enough to configure the anchor peer.' In fact, im sry but I haven't looked into this in depth, please refer to the link above for details.

Comment: Second, the part that is updated before joining is for tx.
It is expressed as after join because the created part considers updating by receiving the block. If you already have a block after creating, it is possible even before joining.

Comment: 1, The link you mentioned is another problem. I guess. When I debug into code, Anchor peers just a host and port, nothing more.

Comment: Third, it was upgraded after proceeding in the form of defining anchor peer in configtx. In this process, the verification process of the configuration and the lifecycle that should actually work are not smooth. The process may actually be meaningful, but it can also be regarded as meaningless. If you fix this well, it seems that you can contribute to the fabric.

Comment: oh really? i will check more details

Comment: I also look into code again. So glad to discuss with you

Comment: Thank you for your opinion. When I checked,there was something wrong with me. the answer was also modified to reflect this.

Comment: Thank you, I checked it again and I'm tring to create channel with anchor peer once time.

Comment: I checked the code. I don't know why but it seems that put anchor peer for first time generate is not implemented. I marked your answer is acceptable. But still don't know why their purpose. It was not hard. Thank you.
Btw, I cloned repo and change something, now it works as what i expected